# TP-Link TLWN725N V2 low signal

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, realtek-wireless

I'm using Lubuntu 15.04 - 64 bit, kernel 3.19.0-18-generic.

My TPlink, is always with low signal(normally 2%).
The other computers are working just fine with other wireless pens, with good quality signal.

1 - first part (http://linuxforums.org.uk/index.php?topic=11261.0):

Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run these commands in sequence:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic git
mkdir ~/RTL8188EU
cd ~/RTL8188EU
git clone git://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu
cd ~/RTL8188EU/rtl8188eu
make
sudo make install
sudo cp -v ~/RTL8188EU/rtl8188eu/rtl8188eufw.bin /lib/firmware/rtlwifi/
sudo depmod -a
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo modprobe 8188eu
```

then, second part to make sure the correct driver is loaded ([Low wireless signal with TP-Link TL-WN725N WiFi dongle](https://askubuntu.com/questions/389153/low-wireless-signal-with-tp-link-tl-wn725n-wifi-dongle?rq=1)):

added this line: blacklist r8188eu

In

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Save and Quit from Text Editor

Then in

```
sudo gedit /etc/modules
```

I added this line at the end of the configuration: 8188eu. Save and Quit from Text Editor again

Then you do

```
sudo depmod -a
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

And before you reboot the system it is important to test these commands:

Check if the module you already blacklisted with

```
lsmod | grep r8188eu
```

If it's not removed then remove it with

```
sudo rmmod r8188eu
```

And finally you do

```
sudo rmmod 8188eu
sudo modprobe 8188eu
```

To refresh the module and you'll have a working with full signal wireless

Reboot!

now, I have a 100% signal connection with ip address, but unable to connect to internet.

The output of iwconfig&ifconfig:

```
wlan0     unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.462 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 30:b5:c2:19:a3:13  
          inet addr:192.168.180.192  Bcast:192.168.180.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::32b5:c2ff:fe19:a313/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:35 errors:0 dropped:3 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2890 (2.8 KB)  TX bytes:3714 (3.7 KB)
```

what's missing?

@Pilot6 route -n output:

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.180.1   0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 wlan0
192.168.180.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0

Comment: I think you did not pay for internet, or something of that kind, like ISP is down.

Comment: Also maybe you forgot to switch off your wired connection. Give output of `route -n`.